# How to build and run a war that acts as a parent and calls a web application(war) inside it using Maven?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

Right now here is how my application is configured.

```
+-- RootCompanyApp 
| 
+-- module-a (com.pab.accountConfiguration)
|    +--- pom.xml //packaged as jar
+-- module-web (com.pab.mainWebApp)
|    +--- pom.xml //web module, packaged as war
--- pom.xml //parent pom with <modules> but not being used right now
```

This is how I do things right now. If i have changes in module-a (accountConfiguration), i run mvn clean install in the module-a directory (actually only "clean install" when using IntelliJ).

To run the project, I run "clean install tomcat7:run -U" via Intelli J in the module-web directory.

You see, the pom.xml in RootCompanyApp is not being used. Now, what I need to do is utilized this pom.xml, instead of building and running the project from the module-web directory, I need to build and run the war from the RootCompanyApp. And then when it runs, it will show a page (this page is maybe on an entirely new project --call it module-dashboard-- that only contains this page )that has a link (link maybe is /webApplication) that I'll click on to go to the module-web application.

Initially, the pom.xml in the RootCompanyApp, i edited it from  pom to war which failed because 
 'packaging' with value 'war' is invalid. Aggregator projects require 'pom' as packaging. I understand that if its going to be a parent pom then it needs to have "pom" as the packaging value, but if this is a pom then how can I build this as a war...